# XSLT Mediator for Tridion 2013 SP1 not working

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1, xslt, xslt-mediator

Recently I'm working on the migration of `Tridion 2011` to `Tridion 2013 SP1` and I came up with an error while publishing saying "Could not find the mediator for type text/xsl".

So I moved my existing `"Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.dll"` to the new `Tridion 2013 SP1` `bin` folder.

Later on I got an another error

> "Instance of an object
>   Tridion.ContentManager.CommunicationManagement.Page could not be
>   created."

Please let me know how I can figure out the solution for this problem.

Thanks

Comment: And why do you think, that XSLT mediator not working?)
Can you show section "tridion.templating/mediators" from your TCM.Config?
Also can you show full error with Stack Trace?(probably you can try to find it in event log).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XSLT mediator was created for SDL Tridion R5.3 up until 2011, since in SDL Tridion 2013, a new Template Building Block type was added, the *XSLT template*.

That was done by adding the XSLT mediator to the release basically, rendering the mentioned extension void. So you should NOT try to install the XSLT mediator extension, just use the built in one instead.

### Update

Not sure if the upgrade process will notice you already have the XSLT mediator extension installed and if it will correctly remove it, just check your `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file and make sure you have the following Template Type (taken from my 2013 SP1 config):

```xml
<add id="10" name="XsltTemplate" titleResource="lblXsltTemplate" mimeType="text/xsl" hasBinaryContent="false" contentHandler="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Xslt.XsltTemplateContentHandler, Tridion.ContentManager.Templating, Version=7.1.0.1290, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=360aac4d3354074b">
  <webDavFileExtensions>
    <add itemType="TemplateBuildingBlock" fileExtension="xslt"/>
  </webDavFileExtensions>
</add>
```

And make sure there are no additional template types mapped to the extension `xslt` or mimetype `text/xsl`.

You will also want to remove the XSLT mediator extension DLLs from the bin folder and the GAC (if they were there).

Comment: Thanks Bart.But when we try to include the inbuilt XSLT mediator and execute it through the template builder we are getting the initial error that is "Could not find the mediator for type text/xsl".

Comment: <mediator matchMIMEType="text/xsl" type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Xslt.XsltMediator" />
I just wonder, why you hadn't get this on upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Bart.Removing the old mediator configurations made my existing inbuilt mediator work.